# How to Update array value

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I need to update my array value of key => icon into new array with another array key => icon

TS:

This is one of my array

```
this.diff = this.arrayVal;
console.log(this.diff);
```

This print the below output as an array

So the output should be.

```
0
: 
{data: 'test'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through one array and get the other arrays' value using the index.

```js
const arr = [{
    icon: 'chevron-left'
  },
  {
    icon: 'chevron-right'
  },
];

const arr2 = [{
    icon: 'fas fa-<insert icon>',
    text: 'file1'
  },
  {
    icon: 'fas fa-<insert icon>',
    text: 'file2'
  }
];


console.log(arr2.map((v, k) => {
v.icon = v.icon.replace('<insert icon>', arr[k].icon);
return v;
}));
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution, It gave the desired output but I need to show the icon key as icon and text key as value, would this solution help me to achieve that @Salketer

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. The current output is exactly the output in your question, so I'm bit lost.

Comment: Never Mind, My bad I didn't ask you the exact answer that I Need, but I made some tweaks on your code it worked fine, Thanks!